# Dell start up error

Tags: hardware-failure

As soon as I start my PC, a pixeled, broken Dell logo appears on the screen and I can't progress any further. I've tried bringing up the repair/safe mode page when I restart, but this doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: a display which is pixelated means one of two things.  The GPU is damaged and should be replace or the monitor is damaged and should be replaced.  This isn't a problem with the windows installation.

Comment: Due to the nature of the failure you've described, this is not a problem anyone here can easily troubleshoot or give advice on. Take it to a technician to be repaired.

Comment: It would help if you could add a picture of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Memory failure. Isolate and test the memory modules individually. One of the memory sticks is most likely causing this issue. You can remove all the memory modules and insert one at a time to locate the problem component. Most sticks should boot up normally but one should be responsible.